# how to force overflow within a flex div parent

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            html,
            body {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .child {
                height: 200vh;
                width: 100vw;
                background: yellow;
            }

            .parent {
                display: flex;
                flex-flow: column;
                height: 100%;
                background: green;
                overflow: scroll;
            }


        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child"> 
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

This outputs a yellow screen because the child overlaps the parent, but no scroll bar is shown for the scroll parent. If I remove the `display:flex` scrolling happens. It also happens when I fill the child with text until it overflows. I would like the child to always make the parent overflow, even without text. Is this possible?

I need to do this because I use a script that adds an empty div at the end of the child in the parent to make the parent scroll until some elements is back in view.

Comment: Do you want it to overflow vertically or horizontally?

Comment: flex-shrink:0 to child element

Comment: You can remove the flex-flow: column; property from the parent CSS and then see your element is scrolling down.

Comment: @BernardBorg, right now vertically but maybe in the future also horizontally.